# Commutator algorithm

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $M \in \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z}).$ Is there an efficient algorithm to write $M$ as a commutator (group commutator, not algebra commutator) [or fail if this is impossible]?

Addendum: answering Mark Sapir's comments (every element in $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is a commutator EXCEPT $-I.$:

*Thompson, R. C.*, [**Commutators in the special and general linear groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1993409), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 101, 16-33 (1961). [ZBL0109.26002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0109.26002).

Comment: It is a hyperbolic group, so the problem of solving equations is decidable. Since it is also virtually free, there should be a polynomial time alforithm.

Comment: "Polynomial time" is not very satisfying :) I would assume that for an actual free group there should be a close-to-linear-time algorithm.

Comment: As a start (for the free group) see https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218196707003597&ved=2ahUKEwjQxJzhuKLnAhUtTt8KHdbUAe4QFjAKegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2fG4-kxtJKTCuGmuqhb-li&cshid=1580082470236

Comment: For the matrix group, it may be easier to solve the corresponding system of 6 polynomial equations with 8 variables. Also if $[x, y]=w$ then $[xy,y]=w$ which may reduce the number of variables.

Comment: @MarkSapir You might be right. The fact that the equations are diophantine (we want integer solutions) is a bit problematic, of course (we are looking at $\mathbb{Z}$ points on some variety).

Comment: Yes, these is a Diophantine problem But one can try to find all real (or even rational) solutions first. It isn't true that over rationals or reals every matrix is a commutator. Right?

Comment: The matrix $-I$ is not a commutator according to https://yutsumura.com/an-example-of-a-matrix-that-cannot-be-a-commutator/

Comment: @MarkSapir And this is the ONLY exception. See Robert Thompson's 1961 Transactions paper.

Comment: @MarkSapir see the OP for reference (added)

Comment: It is not just for $\mathbb{R}$, for any field with at least 4 elements. In particular, for rational numbers.

Comment: For free groups, look at the linear-programming problem studied by Calegari in his proof that scl is rational. I think that writing w as a commutator is equivalent to finding an integer point in the slice with Euler characteristic equal to -1.